# How do I iterate through a list of strings and print each item?

Tags: python, string, list

I have a list of strings and print each of the strings in the list, meaning not `['word1','word2','word3']` but instead: `word1`, `word2`, `word3`.

I tried doing this:

```
for i in list:

    print list[i]
```

but I get the message

> "list indices must be integers, not str"

I am really confused on how I should actually do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
for i in list:
    print i
```

I is the list element: in other words, it takes on the values of the member strings, in order.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't name your variable `list`, since that is a python built-in reserved class. You'll save yourself confusion later. Let's call it `lst`, here.

Now, to your error.

> "list indices must be integers, not str"

`lst[i]` is accessing an *index*, but it "must be an integer". However, `i` is a `str` (A Python string class). What is `i`, though? Well, it is the element `in lst` for the current iteration.

---

You could "debug" your script by just printing `i`, see what it is.

If you were still confused (like you see it printing `1`), then you should print `type(i)`, it will say `<type 'str'>`, and printing `repr(i)` would see `'1'`, so you would print `int(i)` to cast the string `'1'` to an int `1`